# how to set default web page to open when running an app in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible in Eclipse to set the default file to open (to run) when running a web app project? Eclipse runs the current file on focus every time I click the run button. How can I make it open a specific file (i.e. index.jsp) instead no matter what file I am editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the behavior of launching the selected resource in preferences.

Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Launch Operation

Answer (score 0):

Configure `Run Configurations` for your project.. And always run the `Configuration` which u've configured.